# CONSULTA SQL SERVER CON JSON

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

he realizado consulta con MYSQL usan Jquery y Json y todo funciona bien. Pero al querer realizarla contra un SQL SERVER, he obtenido solo mensajes de error variados. Lo que puedo mencionar es que el MYSQL usa Utf8 mientras que el SQL SERVER usa Latin. Ya he probado de todo y siempre me tira: nexpected token < in JSON at position 0   -  o en su defeto   SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. Transcribo los códigos para ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Saludos.

PHP QUE PROCESA Y DEVUELVE

```
<?php


$contador = 0;

$serverName = "SRV-CRR";

// Puesto que no se han especificado UID ni PWD en el array  $connectionInfo,
// La conexión se intentará utilizando la autenticación Windows.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"anon", 'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true);
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $con ) {
 //echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
 //echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$sql = "SELECT nNroDocumento, sApellidoSoltero, ISNULL(sApellidoCasada, '') AS sApellidoCasada, sNombre, sSexo 
FROM stdPacientes where sApellidoSoltero LIKE '%GO%'";


$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con, $sql );

if( $stmt === false) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}


  $json = array();

  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt) ) {


    $json[] = array(
      'name' => $row['nNroDocumento'],
      'description' => $row['sApellidoSoltero']
    );


  }


  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
  echo $jsonstring;

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($con);

?>
```

ARCHIVO JQUERY

```
  // Fetching Tasks
  function fetchTasks() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'vista/vOpisList.php',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        const tasks = JSON.parse(response);

        let template = '';
        tasks.forEach(task => {
          template += `
                  <tr">
                  <td> ${task.name} </td>
                  <td> ${task.description}</td>
                  </tr>
                `
        });

        $('#tasks').html(template);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/205801/edit) tu pregunta y pega los mensajes de error completos.

Comment: Sugiero que publiques una muestra del JSon que produce como salida tu script (con SQL Server).

Comment: tengo un problema similar y se produce por vocales acentuadas o caracteres especiales, hay un problema del encode de los datos con el charset definido, si bien puedo guardar caracteres acentuados no he podido lograr devolverlos en un json, resolviste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código en tu php, es el que posiblemente el causante
`echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE )`